# How to make Terraform provider support import?

Tags: terraform

The Terraform provider I am using doesn't support import for at least one resource:

```
~/Downloads/terraform import module.fra.something.myid myid
module.fra.something.myid: Importing from ID "myid"...

Error: resource something doesn't support import
```

Yet, the [documentation for Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/writing-custom-providers.html) doesn't even mention how such support could be added.
So how to proceed?

Comment: Now they have added this piece of documentation: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-import?in=terraform/providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the ["Import" subsection of the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/resources/import.html). It's in the different part of the document structure.

In short, you need to implement another function. On top of existing:

```
    return &schema.Resource{
        Create: resourceSomethingCreate,
        Read:   resourceSomethingRead,
        Delete: resourceSomethingDelete,
        Update: resourceSomethingUpdate,
        Exists: resourceSomethingExists,
```

implement `resourceSomethingImporter`:

```
        Importer: resourceSomethingImporter,
```

And if your use-case is simple enough, you can re-use existing implementation by referring to:

```
    Importer: &schema.ResourceImporter{
      State: schema.ImportStatePassthrough,
    },
```

Comment: Sadly `schema.ImportStatePassthrough` is not even fully documented, yet